# Why does this non-nullable val become "nullable"?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, callback, type-inference, kotlin-null-safety

So I have a simple callback class:

```
class Callback<T>(
    val onResponse: (T) -> Unit,
    val onError:(Throwable)->Unit
)
```

Now I want to implement a method that handles errors. There may or may not be an `callback` that needs to be invoked.

```
private fun handleServerError(error:IServerError, callback:Callback<*>? = null){
    val reason = error.cause

    when(reason){
        is Because.ServerRejectsLogin -> {
            doAsync { uiThread { mainActivity.longToast("sorry, your session timed out. please log in again.") } }
            IntentManager.doLogin(mainActivity)
        }
        else -> callback?.onError(reason)
    }
}
```

This gets me an error:

> Reference has a nullable type `((Throwable) -> Unit)?` use explicit `?.invoke()` to make a function-like call, instead

What it seems to expect is

```
else -> callback?.onError?.invoke(reason)
```

and I don't quite understand why. Shouldn't the fact that `callback` is not null be sufficient to derive that there must be a non-null `onError` function?

To add insult to injury, if I write

```
else -> callback?.let{it.onError(reason)}
```

then it accepts that but not before warning me that I should

> remove redundant `.let` call

Comment: `Shouldn't the fact that callback is not null be sufficient to derive that there must be a non-null onError function?`

well in your case you marked the `callback` as nullable, so the possibility exists that it might be null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `callback?.onError()` syntax would be correct if you were calling a function called `onError` on the `callback` object with the safe call operator. However, in this case, you are first reading a property of `callback`, and then calling another function on what the property returned.

So instead of the expression consisting of just one step, and two pieces:

```
callback   ?.onError()
```

What you actually have is an expression of three parts, with two operators in a row:

```
callback   ?.onError   ()
```

The last step here, `()`, is a call to the `invoke` operator of the object that `onError` returns:

```
callback   ?.onError   .invoke()
```

However, since the `onError` property is read with a safe call operator, this object might be `null`. In this case, you can't use `invoke` in its operator form (same goes for any other operator, by the way), so you have to explicitly write it out, with another safe call added:

```
callback   ?.onError   ?.invoke()
```

---

As for the intention action telling you that you can remove the redundant `let`: that's a bug, and should be reported on [the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

Comment: Huh, that makes a lot of sense, actually. Thank you. Have you already mentioned this in the tracker or should I go ahead and add it?

Comment: I didn't create an issue for it yet, so go ahead! Maybe link it back here as well.